# Messing images on ListView (even with viewHolder)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, convertview, android-viewholder

As effective using of a `BaseAdapter`, I use a ViewHolder to hold the items for recycling.

Normally I load images with the `ImageLoader` library, and it's OK.

This time I'm loading images from ByteArray, but when I load them and I scroll the ListView, I get a mess.

This is my code:

```
      class ViewHolderItem {
          CircularImageView circularImageView1;
          TextView textView1, textView2;
          ProgressBar progressBar1;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup var3) {
          Scuola scuolaItem = lista.get(position);
          ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;
          if(convertView == null) {
              convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.item_elencoscuole, var3, false);
              viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
              viewHolderItem.textView1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              viewHolderItem.textView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

              viewHolderItem.progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

              viewHolderItem.circularImageView1 = (CircularImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.circularImageView1);

              convertView.setTag(viewHolderItem);
          } else {
              viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem)convertView.getTag();
          }

          viewHolderItem.textView1.setText(scuolaItem.getNome());
          viewHolderItem.textView2.setText(scuolaItem.getDistanzaDaOrigine() + " " + scuola.getUnitaDistanza());

          byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(scuolaItem.getLogoFile(), Base64.DEFAULT);
          viewHolderItem.circularImageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));

      viewHolderItem.progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          return convertView;
    }
```

How could I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: did you use ImageLoader with image place holder?

Comment: How could I use ImageLoader from a `byte[]` or `Bitmap` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get a mess"?

Comment: Imagine I have an "A" image on the first item, "C" image on the third item... if I scroll all the items (imagine I have many more), images got messed up. The "A" gets repeated, goes to the second item, etc.